# Discord Bot - Downloading JSON file from a website and extract certain elements of it

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fetch, discord.js

I'm working on a command that will automatically fetch a file from a link once a day and extract two of the elements in it and send that as a message in a channel.

My issue here is that I'm having issues actually getting the file downloaded. I've been trying several different functions to fetch the file but nothing has worked so far. I have attached one of the functions I've tried below.

```
async function getQuote () {
        const url = "https://quotes.rest/qod?category=inspire";
        const path = Path.resolve(__dirname, 'temp', 'qod.json')
        const writer = fs.CreateWriteStream(path)

        const response = await axios({
            url,
            method: 'GET',
            responseType: 'stream'
        })

        response.data.pipe(writer)

        getQuote();

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            writer.on('finish', resolve)
            writer.on('error', reject)
        })
        }


            fs.readFile('./temp/qod.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
                if (err) throw err;
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                msg.channel.send(data);
    })
```

The file I'm trying to work with here looks something like this:

```
{
    "success": {
        "total": 1
    },
    "contents": {
        "quotes": [
            {
                "quote": "What you do speaks so loudly that I cannot hear what you say.",
                "length": "61",
                "author": "Ralph Waldo Emerson",
                "tags": [
                    "action",
                    "inspire",
                    "leadership",
                    "management",
                    "tod"
                ],
                "category": "inspire",
                "language": "en",
                "date": "2020-08-23",
                "permalink": "https://theysaidso.com/quote/ralph-waldo-emerson-what-you-do-speaks-so-loudly-that-i-cannot-hear-what-you-say",
                "id": "eZ0NtMPtGp8c5eQJOBfJmweF",
                "background": "https://theysaidso.com/img/qod/qod-inspire.jpg",
                "title": "Inspiring Quote of the day"
            }
        ]
    },
    "baseurl": "https://theysaidso.com",
    "copyright": {
        "year": 2022,
        "url": "https://theysaidso.com"
    }
}
```

It wants to download as a json file, but when visiting the link, it is listed as a xml document.

How would I go about getting this downloaded and extracting two lines from it? If you're wondering, the two lines are the quote and author lines.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest simply reading the quote to an object, then creating a string using interpolation and send it on the discord channel:

```
async function getQuote () {
    const url = "https://quotes.rest/qod?category=inspire";

    console.log("getQuote: Reading quote...");

    // Get the response as an object
    const response = await axios({
        url,
        method: 'GET'
    })

    // Use destructuring to get the quote and author
    let { quote, author } = response.data.contents.quotes[0];
    
    // Format our quote
    let data = `${quote} - ${author}`;
    
    // Add a console.log for debugging purposes..
    console.log("getQuote: Sending quote:", data);

    // Send the quote on the channel
    msg.channel.send(data);
}
```

Todays quote would then look like so:

```
Limitations are like mirages created by your own mind. When you realise that limitation do not exist, those around you will also feel it and allow you inside their space.  - Stephen Richards
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I tried this but it doesn't return any result. Tried to run the bot on two different systems with the same result. It detects that the command is called but it doesn't call the function. I don't get any errors tho, so I don't know what could be causing this.

Comment: Oh great, thanks for trying it... it might be worth adding a console.log or two to see whats going on.

Comment: Good idea, I'll try that!

Comment: I tried adding some console.log elements throughout the document but it doesn't spit out anything. I've also checked all references to the file and everything seems fine. Do you have any idea what could be the issue here?

Comment: I'm a bit stumped, if the function is being called, some of the log statements should be called at least.

Comment: I figured out what I did wrong. I made the function but I didn't call it. Didn't figure that one out until I created a console.log element outside of the function. Thanks a lot for the help, it really worked!

Answer (score 0):

I copy your code and run my local machine and everythin fine.

> Limitations are like mirages created by your own mind. When you realise that limitation do not exist, those around you will also feel it and allow you inside their space.  - Stephen Richards

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to write the result to a file and then read from the file which is not efficient. Here's a much simpler way of doing it.

```js
async function getQuote() {
  const url = "https://quotes.rest/qod?category=inspire";

  const response = await axios(url);
  const result = response.data;

  /* 
  result = 
  {
    "success": {
      "total": 1
    },
    "contents": {
      "quotes": [
        {
          "quote": "Limitations are like mirages created by your own mind. When you realise that limitation do not exist, those around you will also feel it and allow you inside their space. ",
          "length": "171",
          "author": "Stephen Richards",
          "tags": [
            "inspire",
            "motivational",
            "positive-thinking",
            "self-empowerment",
            "self-help",
            "self-improvement",
            "wealth",
            "wealth-creation"
          ],
          "category": "inspire",
          "language": "en",
          "date": "2020-08-24",
          "permalink": "https://theysaidso.com/quote/stephen-richards-limitations-are-like-mirages-created-by-your-own-mind-when-you",
          "id": "OLSVpLiSwrWplvCcFgPPiweF",
          "background": "https://theysaidso.com/img/qod/qod-inspire.jpg",
          "title": "Inspiring Quote of the day"
        }
      ]
    },
    "baseurl": "https://theysaidso.com",
    "copyright": {
      "year": 2022,
      "url": "https://theysaidso.com"
    }
  } 
  */

  //this is an array of quote objects
  const quotes = result.contents.quotes;

  //extracting first quote object from the array
  const quoteObject = quotes[0];

  //extracting quote text and author from quote object
  const quote = quoteObject.quote;
  const author = quoteObject.author;
  
  //the >>> will make it look like a quote in discord.
  console.log(`>>> ${quote}\n- ${author}`);
  
  //send the formatted quote to the channel
  msg.channel.send(`>>> ${quote}\n- ${author}`);


  //if for some reason you want to save the result to a file
  fs.writeFile(filePath, result, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Saved!');
  });
}

getQuote();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The thing I'm trying to do is to fetch the author and the quote from a file that will have to be downloaded every time the command is run. The reason for this is that the command is used to fetch quote of the day from the specified URL.

Unfortunately, the code you provided seems to just use that one quote permanently which isn't exactly what I want. I'm hosting the bot on an AWS Server, and i don't really want to go on there through remote desktop, add the new quote and reboot the bot just to be able to send a new daily quote.

Comment: The response from the endpoint is not hard-coded; it's very much dynamic. You can test this by running the code snippet (clicking on 'Run Code Snippet') and checking the logged quote. If you run the command multiple times on the same day, it will give you the same result though. You'll get a different quote the next day. As for writing this comment, this is the quote you get when you run the code snippet:
`I keep asking myself these three questions ... What do you have? What do you want? What will you give up?
- Jack Ma`